# How can i use a jmeter as upstream server and burp suite a proxy server

Tags: jmeter

How can i use a jmeter as upstream server and burp suite a proxy server.
How can i use a jmeter as upstream server and burp suite a proxy server. Basically i have jmeter script and want to send all apis from jmeter to burpsuite scanner

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to configure JMeter to use an upstream proxy, it can be either Burp or anything else.

It can be done:

1. On the individual [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler level:

   [image]
2. Using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-http-request#Best%20Practices)

   [image]
3. Via [command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options):

   ```
   jmeter -H localhost -P 8080
   ```
4. Via [system.properties file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)

   ```
   http.proxyHost=localhost
   http.proxyPort=8080
   https.proxyHost=localhost
   https.proxyPort=8080
   ```

More information: [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)